# Get a string in a variable to create a dynamic link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, href

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a map that has a few locations. Whenever users click on each location, a popup will emerge with some information. I am trying to create a dynamic link inside that popup.

Below is my code in Javascript

```
function parseDescription(message){
    var string=""

    for(var i in message){
        if (i=="CommunityPartner"){
            string+='<span style="font-weight:bold">'+i+'</span>'+": "+message[i]+'</a>'+"<br>"
        } else if (i=="WeitzCECPartner"){
            string+='<span style="font-weight:bold">'+i+'</span>'+": "+message[i]+'</a>'+"<br>"
        } else if (i=="PhoneNumber"){
            string+='<span style="font-weight:bold">'+i+'</span>'+": "+message[i]+'</a>'+"<br>"
        } else if (i=="Website"){
            var link = "http://www."+message[i];
            string+='<span style="font-weight:bold">'+i+'</span>'+": "+'<a href="{{link}}" >'+link+'</a>'+"<br>"
        }
        //string+='<span style="font-weight:bold">'+i+'</span>'+": "+message[i]+"<br>"
    }
    return string;
}
```

[image]

I keep getting this error. I think it's related to the value passed into "a href" :

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Blink%7D%7D
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `{{link}}` in the string, you can try this:

```
var link = "http://www." + message[i];
string += '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + i + '</span>: <a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a><br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax:

```
{{link}}
```

is incorrect, because this part was inside a string it was interpreted by the JS engine as a string.

You can use template strings (backticks `) to insert variables as string into another string. For example:

```
`<span style="font-weight:bold">${i}</span>:<a href="${link}" >${link}</a><br>`;
```

This example assumes that link and i are both variables which you want to insert dynamically into your string. If you have more questions leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the {{link}}. Your code looks like native js and not angular or any other framework. Thus, the characters {{}} inside a string do not mean anything. The url that you get is exactly those characters, escaped. Use plain old string concatination to enter your href value.